# Pandas Question create two aggregations with one being conditionally created

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
label  val
a        0
b       -1
b        0
b        1
a        1
b        1
```

My goal here is to group by the label column and get two aggregated columns.  One that shows the amount of rows in each group (eg. a:2, b:4) and second the proportion in each group where val = 1.  What is the best way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the proportion of a column that satisfies a condition is equivalent to taking the mean of a Boolean Series. This allows for it to be done quickly. Since `s` and `df` share the same index, it's perfectly fine to use one to group the other.

To get multiple aggregations for a column, supply a list that specifies what you want to do.

```
s = df.val.eq(1)
s.groupby(df.label).agg(['size', 'mean'])

#       size  mean
#label            
#a         2   0.5
#b         4   0.5
```

---

When the number of groups becomes large using "tricks" like this can be significantly faster than using a `lambda` because many of the basic `groupby` aggregations have cythonized versions that are extremely performant.

```
# Create a sample df with 20,000 unique groups
df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)
df['label'] = df.index//3

%%timeit
s = df.val.eq(1)
s.groupby(df.label).agg(['size', 'mean'])
#10.8 ms ± 300 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit 
def portion(x): return (x.eq(1).sum())/len(x)
df.groupby('label').val.agg(['size', portion])
#7.93 s ± 82.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def portion(x): return (x.eq(1).sum())/len(x)
df.groupby('label').val.agg(['size', portion])
```

Output:

```
        size portion
label
a       2    0.5
b       4    0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You should make it a separate answer.